# Is there a way to get image name in place of image position in setOnClickListener onClick method under grid view?

Tags: android, android-gridview

I am using grid view example. What i want to know is that is there a way to get the image name when a user clicks on a particular image? Right now we are able to get the position of the image clicked.

Please help me on this.

Comment: What do you mean under "image name"? The id of the drawable maybe?

Comment: thanks inazaruk for replying. For e.g. i have two set of images displayed that is profile.jpg and profile1.jpg clicking on profile1.jpg should give me the name of the image that is profile1.jpg

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First you can used custom gridview like listview..

```
imageviewname.setTag("yourimagename");

imageviewname.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            String imgname = v.getTag();
            // toast message
        }
    });
```

Comment: thanks nik for replying. I have a variable newtext[0] which contains name of the image e.g. profile1.jpg  imageviewname.setTag(newtext[0]);   i have also added String imgname=(String) v.getTag(); But i am getting 06-01 12:37:10.386: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(586): java.lang.NullPointerException
06-01 12:37:10.386: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(586):     at blog.android.sdcard.SDCardImagesActivity$ImageAdapter.getView(SDCardImagesActivity.java:137)

Comment: i have resolved it myself. it was due to variable scope conflict. declaring a global variable and storing the newtext[0] in this variable resolved the issue.